# Disable antialiasing for Graphics.FillRectangle?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm painting a rectangle using `Graphics`:

```
// x and y are arbitrary integers or floats. Doesn't matter!
Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x, y, 5, 5);
```

This produces a black rectangle with an *antialiased* border. **How can I disable antialiasing when painting rectangles?**

The following does not work:

```
Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is subtly different to the 'smoothing' used to fill-in staircases on diagonal lines - instead it's the edges of the rectangle being positioned at the notional centres of pixels.

You need to use

```
Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed
```

(or some other enum value, depending on the precise effect you want)